# Specifying a custom user agent using Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to customize the user agent used for the different GCP calls through [PipelineOptions.setUserAgent](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptions.html#setUserAgent-java.lang.String-).

However, it seems to always fall back to `Apache_Beam_SDK_for_Java/2.6.0`.

Looking at the Beam codebase it seems the user agent is forced by the Dataflow runner: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ce9ee0b034cef66ea3845ca049770b9a354a4fd4/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java#L330.

Is this intentional? Should it be customizable?

Edit: specifying it through the `--userAgent` CLI flag doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam takes it from `sdk.properties` file: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/util/ReleaseInfo.java#L37

You should be able to overwrite `name` and `version` in properties file bundled with your asset. Example: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/resources/org/apache/beam/sdk/sdk.properties